# How add rows to list view in odoo?

Tags: python, xml, treeview, odoo

I have a result data comming from wsdl file and I want to put this data in the treeview of my odoo module:

This is my module architecture : 
init.py (where I import module.py) 
openerp.py (dependencies: Base) 
_module.py (where I've got the main code and everything works fine) templates.xml (Main view going with the main code, no problem)

There is the .xml file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<openerp>
    <data>

    <menuitem name="Document_Binov" id="Doc_Bin" sequence="30" />
    <menuitem name="Documents" id="menu_list_doc" parent="Doc_Bin" sequence="10" />

<!-- Form example --> 
 <record model="ir.ui.view" id="document_form">
  <field name="name">document.form</field>
  <field name="model">document_binov.document_binov</field>
  <field name="type">form</field>
  <field name="arch" type="xml">
   <form string="Documents">
 <sheet>
 <group>
    <label string="Titre"/>
     <field name="titre"/> 
     <label string="Description"/> 
    <field name="description"/>  
    <label string="Type"/>
    <field name="type"/>
    </group> 
     </sheet>
    </form>
  </field>
</record>

<!--Tree view example -->
<record model="ir.ui.view" id="document_tree_view">
 <field name="name">document.tree.view</field>
 <field name="model">document_binov.document_binov</field>
 <field name="type">tree</field>
 <field name="arch" type="xml">
  <tree string="Documents">

      <field name="titre"/> 
      <field name="description"/>
      <field name="type" /> 
  </tree>
 </field>
</record>


 <!-- déclaration d'action -->

 <record model="ir.actions.act_window" id="action_document_work"> 
  <field name="name">Liste des documents</field>
  <field name="res_model">document_binov.document_binov</field>
  <field name="view_type">form</field>
  <field name="view_mode">tree,form</field>
  <!-- <field name="help" type="html"/> --> 
  <field name="document_tree_view" ref="document_form"></field>

</record>    

 <!--déclaration menu -->
<!-- <menuitem id="document" name="Documents" /> -->

<!-- déclaration de menu principale niveau 1-->
<!-- déclaration de menu niveai 1.1(sans action=non cliquable) -->
<menuitem id="document_menu" name="Liste des documents" parent="menu_list_doc" action="action_document_work" sequence="10"/> 

    </data>
</openerp>
```

And there is the .py file:

```
class document_binov(models.Model):
     _name = 'document_binov.document_binov'
     _description = 'visualise les documents'

     titre = fields.Char(default='a')
     description = fields.Char('Description')
     type = fields.Char('Type')
```

[image]

Please help me to put the my result data to the treeview.
Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I edit my question again with more explanation

Answer (score 0):

In the constructor of your document_binov class you should open the file, parse it and fill records one by one. Odoo will manage the rest.

Comment: thanks for your reply. I 'm beginner with odoo development so accept my request. Can you please detail your solution ?      I need your help really .